# Get value for datastore variable in Yocto

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am trying to get a datastore variable.

I know I can do
`bitbake -e <image-name> | grep ^VARIABLE=` to get all the assignments.

This datastore variable, however, contains other variables or datastore variables, so I will have to resolve them recursively in order to get all values.

Is there an easy way to get collected values of a datastore variable for a image??

Comment: Add example of other variables that `VARIABLE` contains, are they in the format: `VARIABLE="other1 other2 .."` or other variables are flags of `VARIABLE` ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM The 1st format: VARIABLE="other1 other2 .."

Comment: So you want to expand  all variables and set the final value back to VARIABLE? like other1=o1 and other2=o2 so VARIABLE would be "o1 o2" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

You have a variable `VARIABLE` that has other variable names like:

```bash
VARIABLE = "OTHER1 OTHER2 OTHER3"
```

and you want to get all values of `OTHER1`, `OTHER2` and `OTHER3` and put them again in the `VARIABLE` variable.

You can do the following:

```bash
VARIABLE = "OTHER1 OTHER2 OTHER3"
VARIABLE_VAL = "${@' '.join([d.getVar(val) for val in d.getVar('VARIABLE').split()])}"
```

Example:

```bash
OTHER1 = "other1"
OTHER2 = "other2"
OTHER3 = "other3"

VARIABLE = "OTHER1 OTHER2 OTHER3"
VARIABLE_VAL = "${@' '.join([d.getVar(val) for val in d.getVar('VARIABLE').split()])}"

OTHER1:append = " other1_1"
OTHER1:append := " ${OTHER2}"
OTHER2:prepend = "other2_2 "
```

If you meant something else, feel free to add a comment and I will edit this reponse accordingly.

Comment: Thx @ TalelBELHADJSALEM! I ran `echo "${@' '.join([d.getVar(val) for val in d.getVar('VARIABLE').split()])}"` and got `zsh: bad substitution`